# Copy dialog, the new "pie-style" in Nautilus, gone if you close the window

Tags: nautilus, 17.10

here Ubuntu Gnome 17.10, thus Nautilus, on Wayland.

I appreciate the small "pie" in the upper side of the window, when you copy some files from a folder to another folder.

The problem is: if I drag something over a folder that I have, e.g., on the desktop... no "pie" appears, even if I open that folder, and I have not found any way to see a copy-in-progress dialog to grab infos about my copy being done.

Is that me?
Is there a keyboard shortcut or similar?
I have read many answers about that, ma none actually pointed to something really working.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I'm on 18.04, that pie does not even show for me when transferring files from an sshfs-mounted location to my desktop. It's maddening.